# Icons in menu are smaller than they should be

Tags: android, menu, icons

**SOLVED:**
I was using icons from sdk v9 (Android 2.3 Gingerbread) which seems to have different dimension. The asset studio also creates icons for 2.3. So I placed gingerbread icons to drawable-xxpi-v9 and for older versions I put icons from SDK v8 to drawable-hdpi and it works fine now

Original question:
Hello I have a little problem.
All the icons in my apk are smaller than the same icons in other apps (Gmail etc.)
This is how it looks like in [my apk](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5860650/small%20icons/myApk.png) and this is the same icon in [Gmail.apk](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5860650/small%20icons/gmail.png).
I have copied these icons directly from SDK  to the specific folders for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi.

Here is an example of a hdpi [icon](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5860650/small%20icons/ic_menu_refresh.png) I use and my menu.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
  android:id="@+id/refresh"
  android:title="@string/refresh"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh" />
 <item
  android:id="@+id/add"
  android:title="@string/add"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_add" />
 <item
  android:id="@+id/login"
  android:title="@string/account"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_login" />
</menu>
```

Does anybody know how to make these icon have the same size as in other apk's?
I have tried the asset studio with no effect.

**UPDATE:** If I reference an icon directly from android (android:drawable) then it has normal size. However not all icons can be referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using icons from sdk v9 (Android 2.3 Gingerbread) which seems to have different size. The asset studio also creates icons for 2.3.
So I placed gingerbread icons to `drawable-xxpi-v9` and for older versions I put icons from SDK v8 to `drawable-hdpi` and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proper `<supports-screens>` element in your manifest.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference If I allow anyDensity devices (which is default BTW)