# Android action bar menu item with icon gets smaller after 4.3 os upgrade

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

## Problem

Until 4.1.2 version, the action bar menu item with icon size is correct (attach 1)

[image]

with the **upgrade to 4.3** version what is shown is the following (attach 2)

[image]

## Code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menuItemLogout = menu.add(0, MENUITEM_LOGOUT_ID, 0, "LOGOUT").setIcon(R.drawable.iv_logout);

    menuItemLogout.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}
```

## The icon

I attach the icon **85x48** painted with black so you can see it:

[image]

## Links and considerations

I already have checked the following links without clearing my issue:

[Icons in menu are smaller than they should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627730/icons-in-menu-are-smaller-than-they-should-be)

[Action bar icon size in Android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519710/action-bar-icon-size-in-android-4-2)
(I have not tried this solution... too hacky)]

[Android dev - Iconography#actionbar](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar)

It seems that some kind of padding is applied to the icon, or the button is not correctly resized, depending on the icon size.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm still having the issue